# What's the correct way to redirect both stdout and stderr in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

Here's the concrete task I'm trying to accomplish. zsh behaves the way I like

```
$ zsh
$ which clang > /dev/null 2&>1 && echo clang || echo gcc
clang
$ which doesntexist > /dev/null 2&>1 && echo doesntexist || echo gcc
gcc
```

But, in bash:

```
$ bash
$ which clang > /dev/null 2&>1 && echo clang || echo gcc
gcc
```

Here's the general case:

```
$ which clang > /dev/null 2&>1; echo $?
1
$ which clang; echo $?
/usr/bin/clang
0
```

There's something wrong with how I'm redirecting output. What's the right way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're redirecting the wrong way:

```
which clang > /dev/null 2&>1; echo $?
```

Should be

```
which clang > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
```

It's probably how either shells allow the former method. In bash it's not the right way. Bash would interpret it instead like:

```
which clang >/dev/null 2 &>1; echo $?
```

In which `2` is added as an argument.

You can verify that by creating a function like

```
e() { echo "$@" >e.log; }
```

And call it as:

```
e 1 >/dev/null 2&>/dev/null
```

And you would get `1 2` in e.log.

In bash it's also simpler if you call your command like this:

```
which clang &>/dev/null; echo $?
```

Also rather than calling an external binary like `which`, use `type -P` instead. No need to redirect stderr output too.

```
type -P clang >/dev/null; echo $?
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using zsh's `&>` operator, which redirects stderr and stdout. The way you've used it suggests you meant `... > /dev/null 2>&1` instead.

I would do this as:

```
$ cc=$( type -P clang gcc othercc | head -n 1 )
$ echo $cc
/usr/bin/clang
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
which gcc >& /dev/null && echo gcc || echo clang
```

Also you can use this:

```
[[ $(which gcc) ]] && echo gcc || echo clang # prints gcc
[[ $(which clang) ]] && echo gcc || echo clang # prints clang
```

This works because in `[[ ]]` empty strings are falsey.