# How to disable stdout/stderr output when `node bin/www`?

Tags: node.js, npm

When `npm start` or `ndoe bin/www`, it will put error to stderr and output `GET / **` to stdout, how to disable the logging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to redirect both stdout and stderr in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624463/whats-the-correct-way-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash)

Comment: remove morgan packegae in app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a bash-shell, you can pipe all output to `/dev/null`:

```
node bin/www > /dev/null 2>&1
```